# Combine rows with duplicates and then remove row

Tags: excel, vba

I've created an excel file that creates an order list for furniture. The list can be anywhere from 100 rows to 3000 rows long depending on the size of the order.

My problem is that the data that creates the order list includes alot of duplicates as shown in the picture.

What I would need help with is to create a macro that takes all matching id numbers and combine it into one row where the quantity is combined. The list price will be the same and the total price is a function taken from quantity*listprice.

[image: img1]

I'm aware that there is several posts regarding problems like mine but i have not managed to find a sulution. I'm not that experienced with coding so would appreciate all help I can get!

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a platform where people solve your problems. You should try it by yourself and ask for help, if things do not work out. You can use a macro and loop over all of your entries. It is hard to explain what you would have to do, other then in code.

Try to understand this piece of code and adopt it to your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cleanDuplicateIDs()

Dim startrow As Integer
Dim IDcolumn As Integer

startrow = 2
IDcolumn = 3

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim amount As Integer
Dim aktID As String

i = startrow
While Cells(i, IDcolumn) <> ""
    aktID = Cells(i, IDcolumn)
    amount = Cells(i, IDcolumn + 1)
    j = i + 1
    While Cells(j, IDcolumn) <> ""
        If Cells(j, IDcolumn) = aktID Then
            amount = amount + Cells(j, IDcolumn + 1)
            Rows(j).Delete
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Wend
    Cells(i, IDcolumn + 1) = amount
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

I am sure, you can solve your problem with something like this.

Comment: You should declare row counting variables as `Long`. Excel has more rows than fit into `Integer`. Also there is no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA at all so you can always use `Long` instead.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I managed to adapt the code to my needs.

Comment: Since the maximum rows in this case are supposed to be 3000, the integer type should be sufficient. I did not know, that there is no benefit to using integers instead of longs. I would assume, that the macro uses less memory when using integers. This would be a tiny benefit. Or is the memory usage the same and the performance less?